# UserWarning: Conversion from CIE-LAB, via XYZ to sRGB color space resulted in 3592 negative Z values that have been clipped to zero

Tags: image, lab-color-space

run `color.lab2rgb(Lab)` ,will have a UserWarning; The message about `Lab` see the graph.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNUj8.png);and l have some debug graph:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCKC0.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we5Pm.png)

how to solve the UserWarning?